# UNIX matching pattern and extraction

Tags: unix

I'm new to unix. I have a file which has network connection details.I am trying to extract only the hostname and port number from the file using shell script.The data is like this "(example.easyway.com=(description=(address_list=(protocol=tcp)(host=184.43.35.345)(port=1234))(connect=port))"

I've 100 lines of connection information like this.I have to extract only the Host name and port and paste it in a new file. can anyone guide me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Oracle TNS configuration to me. Presuming that `host` always comes before `port` this call out to Perl would to the trick

```
perl -ne 'print "$1:$2\n" if(/host=([\w\.-]+).*port=(\d+)/)' < my-tns-config.txt
```

If the order of `port` and `host` is unpredictable then this would work

```
perl -ne 'print "$1:$2\n" if(/host=([\w\.-]+).*port=(\d+)|port=(\d+).*host=([\w\.-.]+)/)' < my-tns-config.txt
```

Check https://regex101.com/ or https://regexper.com for an explanation of those regular expressions.

M.

Comment: \w is for character..what if i have '-' in my Host name .
example:tns scrpit file has 'HOST=User-working.com'
expected result:User-working.com
obtained result:User

Comment: Good point. I have amended the code examples to handle dashes (and dots better).

Comment: perfect..thanks..:).one more question..what if i have two host in same line
example:'Host=User-working Port=1256 lion Host=Lion Port=5263'
obtained output:
   User-working:1256
required output:
 User-working:1256
Lion:5263

Comment: @KAMALASHOK is unclear what you're asking. I think it would be better asked by amending the original question.

Comment: **Input File:**

dash dash (Host=lion) (Port=1256) dash dash (Host=Tiger) (Port=5263)

when i execute 

`echo 'dash dash (Host=lion) (Port=1256) dash dash (Host=Tiger) (Port=5263)' | perl -ne 'print "$1:$2\n" if(/Host=([\w\.-]+).*Port=(\d+)/)' > good1.txt`


**am getting output as**

lion:5263

**I should get**

lion:1256
tiger:5263

Answer (score 0):

There a different ways in Unix to do so, something like

```
sed 's/^..\([^=]*\)=.*port=\([^)]*\).*/\1 \2/' file
```

I think you will not understand this and want something easier now. You can tryit with some steps, checking after each step:

```
cut -d= -f1,7 file | cut -d")" -f1 | cut -c2-
```

The easiest way is, when you are unfamiliar with these tool, is opening the file in some editor, replace global the string `=(description=(address_list=(protocol=tcp)(host=` by a space (or use regular expressions in your editor), the same for `))(connect=port))` and sit for 10 minutes to edit te remainig part of the 100 lines.